# Equation of Hill sphere when the mass ratio is not large

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, approximations, celestial-mechanics, stability

I know of the equation for determining the [Hill sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere). Which is $a(1-e)(m/3M)^{1/3}$. However I noticed that during the derivation of this formula that the assumption that $m\ll M$ is used. But what if this is not the case. What if $M/m$ is less then $100$ or even $10$. What is the formula for the Hill sphere then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve$$\frac{m}{x^2}-\frac{M}{(r-x)^2}+\frac{M(r-x)}{r^3}=0\iff m(r-x)^2r^3-Mx^2r^3+Mx^2(r-x)^3=0,$$a quintic in $x$. It can't be solved with radicals, but you can use numerical methods to improve the aforementioned approximation.